If $ϕ_1(\underset{\sim}{x}),ϕ_2(\underset{\sim}{x})$ be two MP tests of size $\alpha$ ,i.e. Size are equal .Can we say Power would also be equal?
For a Test : $H_0:\theta= \theta_0$ Vs $H_1:\theta= \theta_1$
$P_{H_0}(\underset{\sim}{X} \in \omega)= E_{H_0}(\phi(\underset{\sim}{x}))$ = Size of Test    ; $\omega=Critical\space Region$
$P_{H_1}(\underset{\sim}{X} \in \omega)=E_{H_1}(\phi(\underset{\sim}{x}))$ = Power of Test
Now If $\phi_1(\underset{\sim}{x}),\phi_2(\underset{\sim}{x})$ be two Most Powerful(MP) test of size $\alpha$ i.e $$E_{H_0}(\phi_1(\underset{\sim}{x}))=E_{H_0}(\phi_2(\underset{\sim}{x}))=\alpha$$ , from definition of MP test.
Doubt/Question: Then can we say $E_{H_1}(\phi_1(\underset{\sim}{x}))=E_{H_1}(\phi_2(\underset{\sim}{x})) $? If yes then please provide me the mathematical proof.
I came across a problem where it seems like this is true but did not get a strong proof regarding this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
